# Illegal Argument Exception for loading image

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception, image-loading

I'm currently programming a game and trying to load and image from an `ImageLoader` class and I keep receiving this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1338)
at game.ImageLoader.getImage(ImageLoader.java:24)
at game.TestPanel.<init>(TestPanel.java:38)
at game.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:26)
```

Here is the code to my class that's calling the `ImageLoader` class, yet I also receive an error on my catch block:

```
    public TestPanel ()
        {
        try
        {
            ClassLoader myLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
            backdrop = loader.getImage("resources/Asteroid.jpg");
            ImageLoader test = new ImageLoader();
            ship = test.getImage("resources/Alien-Ship.png");
            InputStream pointStream = myLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/path_1.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner (pointStream);
            objectPath = new PathPoints(s);
            squid = objectPath.getStart();


        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("Could not load: " + e);
        }
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
```

And here is the code for my `ImageLoader` class:

```
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class ImageLoader {

    public Image loadedImage;

        public ImageLoader(){


        }

        public Image getImage(String s){
        try
                {
                    ClassLoader myLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
                    InputStream imageStream = myLoader.getResourceAsStream(s);
                    loadedImage = ImageIO.read(imageStream);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Could not load: " + e);
                }

                return loadedImage;
         }

        }
```

Why is it throwing null!, I have tried to change the path of `resources/Asteroid.jpg` to `/resources/Asteroid.jpg` yet it changed nothing.

Edit: `resources` relates to my classpath because it is the package in which I am storing my image and point resources in.

Comment: Have you tried loading the resource as `loader.getImage("Asteroid.jpg");`?

Comment: I'd verify that the image actually exists within the Jar you are trying to load it from

Comment: Yes, I still receive the same error.

Comment: It's local, I know it exists as I just created it and have loaded it in previous versions.

Comment: Ok, either describe how the `resources` path relates to your classpath, or snap a picture and include it in your question.

Comment: Please share your directory structure.

Comment: @thehoule64 - are you saying that you literally have a package called `resources` in your application?

Comment: Yes I am saying I have a package called resources that is storing all my image resources

Comment: My directory structure is as follows: 
My project - `Game Name`
My package - `Play`
My Second Package - `resources`

Comment: @thehoule64 If you are using any IDE, can you just take a snapshot and show us the directory structure. It looks like that the file mapping is incorrect

Comment: @Jatin I do know I can do that, but I cannot upload any images to stack overflow because I do not have a sufficient amount of points.